# Angular Js :Conditionally how to disable all button and links?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have one condition in controller. If the condition return true, then I have to disable all links and `ng-click`s

How we can do :-

```
Controller : $scope.disableActions = true;
```

In HTML

```
<button type="button" ng-click="ignoreAndRedisplay()" ng-disabled="disableActions">OpenClick</button>
```

So by doing this I have to write everywhere `ng-disabled="disableActions"`, it will be redundant , How we can improve this for `n` number of button and links?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What I'll suggest you to do for such cases would be, just put those all buttons inside single `fieldset` and apply `ng-disabled` over that `fieldset`, the controls which are inside that field set will automatically get `disabled` if `ng-disabled` expression gets evaluated to `true`

```
<fieldset ng-disabled="disableActions">
   <button type="button" ng-click="ignoreAndRedisplay()">OpenClick</button>
   <button type="button" >Some Other button</button>
   <button type="button" >One more button</button>
   ...
</fieldset>
```

[**Demo Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/mWr83tDspC3ky2sL0g6l?p=preview)

---

As in comment you OP asking for disabling `anchor` tag. Basically you can't disable `anchor` tag. You could try below hack to make it working.

```
fieldset[disabled] a { 
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/YIb2vXJkFoqjalC53Vyt?p=preview)

Comment: that's out of the box.. +1 :)

Comment: @PankajParkar it is working for all except elements which is inside <table> tag

Comment: @RaviUbana what do you mean by that, could you please create plunker or something?

Comment: Yes @PankajParkar Please have a look http://plnkr.co/edit/YIb2vXJkFoqjalC53Vyt?p=preview

Comment: Agree @PankajParkar But In my case i am going to disable full filed-set . 
case 1: In filed-set i am able to disable all links 
case2 : In filed-set I am not able to disable link which is under table tag

Comment: @RaviUbana you're not understanding core problem.. You can't disable anchor tags.. so how can fieldset can do that for you, you have to do some manual work.. you could add CSS rule for the same `fieldset[disabled] a { pointer-events: none;}` that would fix your issue..

Comment: checkout this updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YIb2vXJkFoqjalC53Vyt?p=preview)

Comment: amazing method it is, great;

Answer (score 1):

`ng-disabled` it the right way to do it. It is reduntant or not.

If you have an n number of links and button, use this bad practice of
add this disabled attribute using a

```
$watch('disableAction',function(value){
   if(value==true){ 
    //use a selector here to select all your a and button elts and add a 
    //disabled="disabled" attribute.
   }
   else {
   // remove that disabled attribute
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create your **own directive**, but `ng-disabled` is the correct way, as JinsPeter said

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you will have to write everywhere `ng-disabled` as you are writing those `buttons` So  it the right way to do it. It is redundant or not.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-disabled` is best. `$scope.disableActions` can use multiple place and affect all place.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app ng-init="disableActions = false">
<button ng-disabled="!disableActions">OpenClick</button>
<button ng-disabled="!disableActions">Second Click</button>
<button ng-disabled="!disableActions">Third Click</button>
<button type="button" ng-click="disableActions = !disableActions">Enable/Disable</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting `ng-disabled` on all of the links will cost performance issues but its the right way to do it. But if you don't want some UI changes you can do it right in the controller.

```
$scope.ignoreAndRedisplay = function () {
    if ($scope.disableActions) return;
    // your code here
}
```